# Google Admin SDK Unable to Create User - Exception 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to create a user using C# and the google-admin-directory_v1-rev24-csharp-1.7.0-beta client libraries however I keep geting an exception:

```
Google.GoogleApiException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Not Authorized to access this resource/api [403]
Errors [
    Message[Not Authorized to access this resource/api] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]

Source=Google.Apis
ServiceName=admin
StackTrace:
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug    \output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 102
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\darin.BASEHEX\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects    \ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 55
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I started by creating a project in the Developers console, under the APIs settings page I turned on the ADMIN SDK, under the Credentials page I created a Service Account and downloaded the p12.key certificate, I filled out the Consent Screen and then I went to the Security page on the Admin Console, selected the Advance tab, selected the Manage third party OAuth Client access, pasted in the Client ID from the Service Account I created and assigned the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user/. The exception is being raised on the line:

```
User results = service.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();
```

The complete C# program is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String serviceAccountEmail = "A bunch of alpha numerics@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(

               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) 

               {
                   Scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser },

                   User = "admin@mydomain.com"  <-------- Added ADMIN User to fix

               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.

            var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()

            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "User Provisioning",
            });

            User newuserbody = new User();
            UserName newusername = new UserName();
            newuserbody.PrimaryEmail = "bbacon@mydomain.com";
            newusername.GivenName = "Bob";
            newusername.FamilyName = "Bacon";
            newuserbody.Name = newusername;
            newuserbody.Password = "iambacon";

            User results = service.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like it is something really simple I am missing however I have run out of any ideas on what to look at.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that the admin SDK is enabled in this project? In general 403 status code is a result of not enabling the API, so please make sure it's enabled.

Comment: Hello Peleyal,  Yes, the ADMIN SDK is turned on for the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like that your service account is impersonating any users in this call.  When you want to use a service account to create a new user, you need to impersonate as the administrator account (Note: only administrator can create users).

Take a look at this Drive example for domain wide delegation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

You can see that for the .net portion, it has this extra line:

ServiceAccountUser = userEmail

You need to create a service object authorized with the service account that will acts on behalf of the given user.

Comment: Thank You Emily!  That was it.  Had to add the User member to the ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer.  I have edited the source above for reference for other poor old sods like me banging their heads against the wall.