# Unable to update password - GoogleApiException - Not Authorized to access this resource

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to update users password in GSuite using OAuth 2.0

I am encountering the following exception:

UpdateEmailUserPassword    Google returned an error against this user. Please check Google exception details and make sure this is a valid existing user

UpdateEmailUserPassword    Google Exception Details : The service admin has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Not Authorized to access this resource/api [403]
Errors [Message[Not Authorized to access this resource/api] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]

I can confirm that the admin account used is a super admin account with all API Scopes allowed for the ClientID and Service Account. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20960948/5832311), you need to create a [service object](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) authorized with the service account that will acts on behalf of the given user. Try adding the User member to the `ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer`.

Sample:

```
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
  new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) 

  {
   Scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser },
   User = "admin@mydomain.com"  <-------- Added ADMIN User to fix
  }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```